What is the dividing line between a segulah and nichush
The Torah in Leviticus 19:26 prohibits the following of omens, also known as issur nichush. I am  curious what the dividing line between a Segulah, which are kabbalistic charms or signs of certain fortune and nichush is, because both seem to involve prediction of an event because of some supernatural force unrelated. Why does Halacha allow the former but not the latter?

What is a segulah, what is a nichush, and how do you think they are similar are details that will improve your question

How do you know a segulah is a kabbalistic charm or sign? What is a kabbalistic charm or sign? How do you know a segulah predicts an event?

It's a whole discussion in the Gemara. The best English language book I am aware of is https://www.amazon.com/Faith-Folly-Occult-Torah-Perspective/dp/0873065360

@N.T. Which gemara

Chullin beginning of seventh perek iirc.
